# Partial form with nested routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I have two models -- `User` and `Entry` -- that are related through a `has_many` relationship (a User has many Entries).  I'm using RESTful routing, and have the following in my routes.rb file:

```
map.resource :user, :controller => "users" do |user|
  user.resources :entries
end
```

This seems to work, but in my partial _form file, when I do this:

```
form_for [@current_user, @entry] do |f|
  # Form stuff
end
```

It generates a URL like this:

> /user/entries.%23%3Cuser:0xb6a6aea8%3E

instead of

> /user/entries

Am I missing something?

I should note that the correct classes are applied to the form when doing creation vs. editing, so it does seem to be correctly interpreting what I'm *trying* to do -- it's just that I can't submit the form to an invalid url.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.  Instead of doing:

```
form_for [@current_user, @entry] do |f|
  # Form stuff
end
```

I needed to be doing:

```
form_for [:user, @entry] do |f|
  # Form stuff
end
```

That is, instead of using the `@current_user` object itself, I just had to tell the `form_for` what my `@entry` object was scoped to (in this case, the `user` class).

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you can't nest resources from resource (singular).
Try to make

```
map.resources :users do |user|
  user.resources :entries
end
```

moreover, that it's better to use resources for users.

Comment: I'm not sure this is better.  When a user is looking at *their* entries, I don't want the user ID to be part of the URL (it's unnecessary and invites tampering).  That is, I'd much rather have /user/entries than /user/1/entries.

Comment: I was wrong: you can nest resources from resource. But if you do it you don't have to write both objects in your form_for (user and entry).